# How to install nvidia driver ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have been trying to install nvidia driver on my ubuntu 16.04 and I have a GTX 940MX graphic card. (dual graphic card)

I tried to install ubuntu with **additional driver** utility, but **nvidia-smi** still outputs nothing:
[image]

```
$ nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi: command not found
```

But in fact, I can install **tensorflow-gpu** and run tensorflow successfully. Could anyone help me figure out how to get **nvidia-smi** work? Becuase I am installing other API at the same time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, install a driver like this

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
```

Then reboot